# Removing a noisy pattern (like chess board) from image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filtering

I have a set of random images called dictionary (top in attached image). Any probe image is represented as a linear combination of the dictionary elements.
Here is the dictionary and a reconstructed sample image:
[image]

[image]

For this purpose the probe image is divided to 16*16 blocks. Each block is a linear combination of dictionary elements. The reconstructed image have a pattern like chess board in some regions, How can I remove this pattern and improve the image visualization? 
I've tried some filters (`medfilt2`, `wiener2`) but it didn't help.

Comment: What about a gaussian filter, such as `imgaussfilt(I, 3);`?

Comment: It makes it better but the image is blured!

Comment: I added my method as an answer (including resulting images) for comparison with other methods. Maybe, you should add the results of your trials too.

Comment: You'll see fewer artifacts as you increase the number of gratings. These are compression artifacts, you cannot avoid them. Compare with JPEG compressed images, they show the same problem when the compression ratio is high. You can probably filter some of this out, but it will always be a compromise between sharpness and artifacts. Look for regions with high gradient at the boundaries of your 16x16 blocks, those are likely artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaussian filtering seems appropriate to me in this case. Note the image does not contain enough information to reconstruct the image exactly. Therefore, one should always make the trade of between blurring and a sharp but rasterised image.

```
figure
sigma = 3; % smaller value => sharper but more rasterised
Ifilter = imgaussfilt(I, sigma); 
imshow(Ifilter);
```

The left image (`sigma = 3`) is less rasterised, but the right image (`sigma = 2`) is sharper.

[image: sigma = 3]
[image: sigma = 2]